# Delete orphan child after updating one to many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a one to many relationship from a class A to B. This relationship is not optional, so each object of the class B should have exactly one object of the class A associated. The inverse is not true, an object of the class A may have 0 to any amount objects of the class B.

When I update an object of type A, it may stop pointing to an object of type B it was pointing before. This forces the inverse relationship to be nil, corrupting the db.

After this update I start to see an error similar to:

```
Exception Reported Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
```

With the NSValidationErrorObject being of type B and the NSValidationErrorKey being this inverse relationship.

I'd like to delete any useless object of type B after any update done to A. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you delete the object B when you're updating the object A?

Comment: On one hand, I'd like to keep the consistency automatically. I don't want to worry about those updates manually. On the other hand, the objects are updated inside a generic library we use I should not being modifying (and I can't for this case). The objects are analyzed on runtime and modified following a description in a dictionary. Basically, we never update the object directly, but through a generic library that can handle any kind of object and I can't add new logic to it.